# Select Any Sibling

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Are `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` the only options for ***explicitly*** selecting siblings?

**Simplified Version of Markup**

```
<ui-view>
  <descendant> <!-- 1 -->
    <descendant> <!-- 2 -->
      <descendant> <!-- 3 -->
        <descendant> <!-- 4 -->
          <descendant> <!-- 5 -->
            <sibling>
              <child></child> <!-- comments_author -->
              <child></child> <!-- comments_timestamp -->
            </sibling>
            <sibling></sibling> <!-- comment (in comments_comment) -->
```

**Script**

```
# 1. Select All Comment Threads
comments_threads = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//ui-view//div[@class="commentLayout"]')

for thread in comments_threads:
    # 2. Select All Comments in Each Thread
    comments_comment = comments_threads.find_elements_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "commentLayout-text")]')

    for comment in comments_comment:
        # 3. Select Author of Each Comment
        # comments_author = comments_threads.find_element_by_xpath('./*[contains(@class, "commentLayout-account")]')

        # 4. Select Timestamp of Each Comment
        # comments_timestamp = comments_threads.find_element_by_xpath('./span[contains(@class, "commentNote")]')
```

The issue is that `3` and `4` have to be selected in relation to each `comment` item of the nested loop, and I would like my code to be as flexible as possible.

Selecting any sibling to match the desired node would be a lot more flexible than, say, using `preceding-sibling` to match the desired node.

One solution would be to select the parent node and then select any child that matches a particular condition, but, if possible, using any sibling as a selector would certainly be more flexible and even more efficient.

Is it not possible to select ***all*** siblings?

Comment: Posting code that never uses `preceding-sibling` or `following-sibling` but asking how to get all siblings is rather confusing.  Your question would be clearer if you posted sample markup and explained what you're trying to select based upon some invariant in the markup.

Comment: i thought my question was fairly clear, but the sake of clarity i'll post a simplified version of the markup. anyways, to put it simply, `comments_author` and `comments_timestamp` are preceding siblings of `comment`.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB i am asking about the actual problem. i'm wondering whether or not it is possible to select ALL siblings instead of just `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`???

Comment: @DebanjanB so then how would i select ALL siblings of the 2nd sibling and only the siblings of the 2nd sibling?

Comment: @DebanjanB as i stated in my original question, the path has to be "in relation to each `comment` item of the nested loop" or in other words **relative**...

Comment: That is the reason, I have asked you instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do? What are the _Manual Steps_ you are going to _Automate_?

Comment: @DebanjanB what are you talking about? what exactly is confusing you about the question? you clearly misread my question and you're trying to blame me for asking about something i never even mentioned???

Comment: @Anthony There is no blame game here. Your question is unclear and without any code trials . See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DebanjanB the question is simple: in the context above, how do i **explicitly** select ALL of the siblings with a selector that is relative to the 2nd sibling. can't get much clearer than that...

Comment: There is no `preceding-and-following-siblings` or `siblings` axis in XPath, nor are they needed.  Your refusal to provide an actual [mcve] rather than sketches is prohibiting us from providing you with a more detailed answer.  The structure of your question does resemble an XY-Problem as @DebanjanB suggests.  If your question is simply is there a `siblings` axis, then the simple answer is **no**.  The "other options" you seek will depend upon the specifics of your actual markup, not an abstract sketch of it, and your actual goal, not a method expressed in terms of a perceived best approach.

Comment: @kjhughes there is no `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` in XPATH? you're joking, right?? aside from that, you seemed to answer the question just fine in your last comment. i was never seeking any "other options". i'm baffled how you guys are consistently misinterpreting my question

Comment: I said, "There is no `preceding-and-following-siblings` or `siblings` axis in XPath," and I meant exactly that.   Re-read it as offering two names for the axis that you were hoping existed.

Comment: @kjhughes i see what you were getting at with that now. myb

Answer (score 1):

Use below selector :

```
//"your div"[position()=1] , just change to any position as you require.
```

I am just trying to give an idea but do not know if that will work out for you or not.
Please have a look at this post for further explanation on position in xpath:
http://seleniumone-by-arun.blogspot.com/2013/04/64-position-xpath-function.html

Comment: `//"your div"[position()=1]` can be simplified like this `//"your div"[1]`

Answer (score 1):

I think this would select all siblings for "thisnode":

`//thisnode/../*`

/.. means select the parent (go up one level)

/* means select every child (go back down one level)

Comment: Yes, select the parent node. Let me edit to add clarity

Answer (score 0):

There is no combined `siblings` axis in XPath – just `preceding-sibling` or `following-sibling`.

You can generally achieve any goal regarding sibling elements via conditions on the children of an element's parent.  Details will be particular to the invariants in the targeted markup.  Use the `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` axes when ordering is important among siblings; otherwise, write conditions on the children of the parent element.